# How to predicate on something having a signed numeric type?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, conditional-compilation, typeof, typeid

Suppose I have some templated code which does the following:

```
T x = foo();
T y = -x;
```

Now, if T is a non-numeric type (or which doesn't have the unary minus implemented), the compilation will simply fail. But if it's an unsigned int, unsigned short etc., it will succeed, with a warning. So I would like to be able to do

```
T x = foo();
if (/* magic condition */ {
    T y = -x;
}
```

Can I write express the condition - which is checked either at compile time or at run time - of T's type being some signed numeric type? e.g. using typeid?

**Note:**

- An assertion would also be nice, but I'd like something more flexible.

Answer (score 6):

C++11 has the `is_unsigned` trait, which you can use in a `static_assert`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value);

    T x = /* ... */
    T y = -x;

    /* ... */
}
```

If you need the check to be more dynamic, then just stick it in an `if` condition:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    if (!std::is_unsigned<T>::value) {
        /* To arrive here and for the following
           not to error out, we must have a numeric
           type that's not unsigned! */

        T x = /* ... */
        T y = -x;
    }
    else {
       /* Do something else for unsigned numeric
          types */
    }
}
```

More complex solutions involve overloads, `std::enable_if` and all sorts of other template metahackery, but the above may be all you need.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to address my clarification?

Comment: @einpoklum Huh, who would have thought that when you need a dynamic branch you would use if :).

Comment: @einpoklum: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Well, partially, since the predication does not save me a compiler warning about type conversion to/from unsigned in the block surrounded by this condition.

Comment: Back to tag dispatching, then.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

```
static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "Not unsigned!");
```

(You need to include type_traits for this to work.)

You can then naturally adjust your compilation process, potentially even with `enable_if` if you're sure there is no other way :).

Comment: I want an `if (...)`, not an assertion. Will clarify my question.

Comment: @einpoklum Then just use tag dispatching. Though I'm not sure what you would do in the `else` case (well Ok, that warning is downright stupid in the first place, given that unsigned minus is perfectly well-defined).

Comment: @ChristianRau: You mean, as in [here](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching)?

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, it seams. You basically make two overloaded methods with an additional argument `void foo_impl(..., std::true_type)` and `void foo_impl(..., std::false_type)` (or whatever your actual method signatures look like) and then from the main method you call the one you need, letting the `std::is_unsigned<T>` do the overload selection (as it is derives either from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`): `void foo(...) { foo_impl(..., std::is_unsigned<T>()); }`. (Of course the dots are placeholders, not actual dots).

Comment: @einpoklum Of course you could also employ `std::enable_if` and SFINAE, but for things like this SFINAE might be a rather complicated solution compared to tag dispatching.

Comment: TBH a simple `if (std::is_unsigned<T>::value)` might be what's wanted. The compiler will almost certainly optimize it.

Comment: I need to get better at guessing what people actually want.